# Docker: ssmtp in php container says "Cannot open mail:25"

Tags: email, php, docker, ssmtp

There is an error if to call php mail function or run it using `/usr/sbin/ssmtp -t`:

> Cannot open mail:25

The configuration of `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`

```
root=postmaster

mailhub=mail.domain.com

hostname=6836e93c...
FromLineOverride=YES
```

tried to change mailhub to default mail, but no luck.

Was thinking about to write 50 port to EXPOSE section in dockerfile. But it does not help. Does any have idea how to fix it?